# User comments on my username, starting off-topic discussion - flag declined

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

I disagreed with a comment suggesting an edit, and received a rather weird response:

> @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica It is not standard English. My arguments are clear. You make the site accessible to all or you create a youth subculture clique. As you have chosen to politicize your handle, I would encourage you to think beyond gendered pronouns.

The discussion then went off a tangent, exactly as I thought. That's why I flagged the comment that started it as *Unfriendly or unkind* instead of replying.

I would like to know what was the correct flag for a comment that is trying to invite irrelevant discussion in an aggressive way.

Note that I'm not asking at all about whether *tl;dr* is appropriate abbreviation, although that sure would be interesting thing to discuss in another meta post.

Comment: I cleaned up the comments, and would prefer they not be preserved here indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks, but I was also hoping to know why the flag was declined. Surely there must be a reason.

Comment: More generally, are moderators obliged to provide flag decision justification?

Comment: @James Flag decisions indirectly set a policy. If mean comments do not get deleted because moderator doesn't feel like it, people will be less likely to report them and users who are mean will be feel empowered to continue starting such discussions. Obviously knowing that a moderator does not care about off topic discussions would be useful for the next moderator election.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica I think the actual answer is more likely to be in the realm of "hit the wrong button" or "didn't recognize from the comment that was flagged the scope of the whole discussion" - in other words, pretty boring. "Does not care about off topic discussions" sounds to me like a pretty bad-faith-assuming guess, and I disagree strongly with flag decisions setting policy. It would be especially bad to apply that logic to the larger sites that handle way way more flags.

Comment: I'd also add that you can always raise a new custom flag if you feel a flag was declined in error, just be polite about it. Something like, "My last flag was declined, possibly in error - can a moderator review this whole conversation and check if the comments should be removed?"